# Sort List which I use to fill ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox

Hello I've got code to fill ComboBox like this:

```
public ListBox fillComboBox(ListBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Clear();
    foreach(string[] s in SO)
    {
        if (s[1].Split(',')[1].Equals("G5IDD"))
        {
            cb.Items.Add(s[1].Split(',')[3]);
        }
    }
    cb.Sorted = true;
    return cb;
}
```

In result I've got values sorted like this:

2.1
2.10
2.15
2.2
2.20

But I want it sorted like this

2.1
2.2
2.10
2.15
2.20

SO is ArrayList build by Arrays of string.

Can someone help me sort it way I want?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Values can be like 
4545_3434.2.1/1
4545_3434.2.1/2
4545_3434.2.2
4545_3434.2.2/1

Comment: Add the items as `double` or similar type, it will be sorted correctly. Strings are sorted differently than numeric sorting.

Comment: Why 2.2 is "smaller" than 2.10? Even string or double will be sorted like you got. Can you define the rule, than sort will not be complicated.

Comment: @user2136076 because it is string. There is no smaller bigger in string. String sorting rules are different. I guess it is because `2.2` is 3 in length where as `2.10` is 4.

Comment: @user2136076 - If those are version numbers, than 2.2 is smaller than 2.10.

Comment: You need to explain what the expected output of your new values should be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would suggest.  No need for IComparer.  This obviously assumes that the input will always be in the format of [int].[int].

```
public ListBox fillComboBox(ListBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Clear();
    foreach(string[] s in SO.ToArray().OrderBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.ToString().Split('.')[0])).ThenBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.ToString().Split('.')[1])))
    {
        if (s[1].Split(',')[1].Equals("G5IDD"))
        {
            cb.Items.Add(s[1].Split(',')[3]);
        }
    }
    return cb;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the numbers treated as version, you can use the Version class.

```
public Version String2Version(string str)
{
    string[] parts = str.Split('.');
    return new Version(Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
}

public ListBox fillComboBox(ListBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Clear();
    foreach(string[] s in SO)
    {
        if (s[1].Split(',')[1].Equals("G5IDD"))
        {
            cb.Items.Add( String2Version(s[1].Split(',')[3]));
        }
    }
    cb.Sorted = true;
    return cb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom comparer(IComparer) in your code to achieve it,
I have provide an example.You have to change the logic of

```
public int Compare(object a, object b)
```

To achieve your specific requirement

```
class Program
{
    private static ArrayList arl;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        arl = new ArrayList();

        arl.Add("2.1/1");
        arl.Add("2.1/2");
        arl.Add("2.2");
        arl.Add("2.2/1");
        arl.Sort(new IDDSort());
        foreach (var value in arl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.Read();           
    }
}


public class IDDSort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;

        var xparts = x.ToString().Replace("/","").Split('.');
        var yparts = y.ToString().Replace("/", "").Split('.');

        var length = new[] { xparts.Length, yparts.Length }.Max();

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int xint;
            int yint;

            if (!Int32.TryParse(xparts.ElementAtOrDefault(i), out xint)) xint = 0;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(yparts.ElementAtOrDefault(i), out yint)) yint = 0;

            if (xint > yint) return 1;
            if (yint > xint) return -1;
        }

        //they're equal value but not equal strings, eg 1 and 1.0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this. But not work.
    public class IDDSort : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object a, object b)
        {
            decimal aDec;
            decimal bDec;
            if (decimal.TryParse((string[])a[1].Split('.')[(string[])a[1].Split('.').Length - 1].Replace("/", ""), out aDec) && decimal.TryParse((string[])b[1].Split('.')[(string[])b[1].Split('.').Length - 1].Replace("/", ""), out bDec))
            {
                return aDec.CompareTo(bDec);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Array.Sort(SO, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
```

(if SO is the array with your version numbers)

Comment: What is `AlphanumComparatorFast()`?

Answer (score 0):

Derive from ListBox and override Sort method implementing your own algorithm. For example the one suggested by Feroc.

Check link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hello I achieved my goal by coping part of array to list. (I needed only names on list not whole arrays). And used lambda expression for it.

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => Int32.Parse(x.Split('.')[2].Split('/')[0]))
            .ThenBy(x =>
            Int32.Parse(x.Split('.')[2].Split('/').Length > 1 ? x.Split('.')[2].Split('/')[1] : x.Split('.')[2].Split('/')[0])
        ).ToList();
```

So now I got it sorted like this:
0001.1
0001.2
0001.2/1
0001.2/2
0001.3
0001.3/1
etc.

Thanks everyone for help.